# KSQL and lookup Table akka GlobalKtable akka broadcast Join?

Tags: ksqldb

Does KSQL support GlobalKtable join with Ktable ?

I could not find anything like that at this point. If not is there any known workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does KSQL support GlobalKtable join with Ktable ?

KSQL doesn't support global tables yet.

> If not is there any known workaround ?

There's no workaround for KSQL.

Comment: Related github issue https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/816 `Broadcast Joins via GlobalKTable`

Answer (score 0):

try this course on pluralsight https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/kafka-streams-ksql-fundamentals/table-of-contents